# Search for a list of emails with imaplib python

Tags: python

I am facing a following problem, I want to have an allowed senders list in my email parser so it will look like:

```
allowed_emails = ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@gmail.com"]
```

I want to use this list in this line, for now it works only with one allowed_sender, how to send a list as an argument?

```
result, data = mail.search(None,'(UNSEEN FROM "%s")' % allowed_sender)
```

Comment: Why do you want to send a list as an argument? Why not just loop over the list and call the function for each of the arguments in it?

Comment: @Denziloe, that is a good advice, probably I will do it, my aim is to save the attachments found in the unread mails every XXX minutes, so I will need just to loop my program for each member of "allowed_emails" list

Comment: You could always simply extend whatever module you're using. Python is a very open language with easy to read and easy to write libraries. EDIT: I know this won't chance the fact that a loop is needed, but it'll allow for a different method call.